# In android studio design of app in real device changes from its Xml view on android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-xml

[Real device vie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idc8P.png)[XML view  of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyyUQ.png)

Comment: Please add relevant code and a description of the issue to your question. Do not just post images

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using `constraint layout` but there are no constraints because of which all the views get pushed towards the top left corner.

That, of course, is just a guess.

Comment: I am using relative layout but you are right all the views gets pushed on top left  Android studio cant find declaration of element 'Relative ayout'